# PHP/Drupal/JavaScript Cookie encoding

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, encoding

I have a cookie which I am setting based on data in a field in Drupal.  When I write the cookie using PHP the extended ASCII characters are shown as hex-codes (e.g. %7E) but if I write a similar cookie with JavaScript then the extended ASCII characters are show in the cookie as single characters (e.g. ~ ).

This is the string I want in my cookie.

```
Section1~email,email.calendar,calendar.wordpresssml,wordpress.moodlesml,moodle.maharasml,mahara.gdrive,gdrive.eportfolio,eportfolioblogs.wiki,wiki.youtube,email.feature,feature|Section2~reader,reader|
```

If I use

```
setcookie("p", "Section1~email,email.calendar,calendar.wordpresssml,wordpress.moodlesml,moodle.maharasml,mahara.gdrive,gdrive.eportfolio,eportfolioblogs.wiki,wiki.youtube,email.feature,feature|Section2~reader,reader|", $expire);
```

I get     `Section1%7Eemail%2Cemail.calendar%2Ccalendar.wordpresssml%2Cwordpress.moodlesml%2Cmoodle.maharasml%2Cmahara.gdrive%2Cgdrive.eportfolio%2Ceportfolioblogs.wiki%2Cwiki.youtube%2Cemail.feature%2Cfeature%7CSection2%7Ereader%2Creader%7C`

rather than the string I want.  If I write the cookie using JavaScript it works fine. I know this is an encoding issue but I would really like PHP to write the cookie using the full set of Extended ASCII characters.

Comment: Could you show some code with examples of the strings which are being encoded? / Current results / Desired results

Comment: `~` is not extended ASCII -- it's part of the base 7-bit ASCII characterset (char 126, if memory serves  .... which = 7E of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is this a problem? You have to remember that this will appear in the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header and by not encoding it you will always have to remember what the special characters are and avoid using them. With encoding, you don't have to worry about that.

With PHP, when you do `$_COOKIE['p']` it will appear as you originally intended. If you want to extract it in Javascript using `document.cookie` or something, then you can use `decodeURIComponent(cookieValue)`.

Comment: Thanks, I did it as you suggested and that works. Wasn't the major rewrite nightmare I thought it would be! And, yes, probably the way I should have done it from the start :-)